# Remove space between factors (years) on x-axis for grouped barchart

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have grouped bar-chart with year as the grouping factor on the x-axis. I have data for 2012 and 2018 only. There is space on the x-axis for 2013 to 2017, I want to remove this space.

```
plot2012and2018 <- ggplot(GYB, aes(x = Year,)) +
geom_bar(aes(color = Cast, fill = Cast),
       stat = "count", position = position_dodge(0.8),
       width = 0.7) +
scale_color_manual(values = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF"))+
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#0073C2FF", "#EFC000FF"))+
labs(y= "Count", x= "Year", title="GYB 2012 and 2018")
plot2012and2018
```

Comment: Could you provide the GYB data?

Comment: Make `x=factor(Year)` and the space should disappear.